# get all but first argv array splice in c

Tags: c

I want to turn my `char **argv` into another `char **` but exclude the first element (which in my case is always going to be the program name)

I thought `&argv[1]` would work, but I get seg faults now.

---

So like in python, all but the first element of a list can be done like this

```
>>> argv = [1, 2, 3]
>>> argv[1:]
[2, 3]
```

I want to get `argv[1:]` but in C.

Comment: `&argv[1]` or, equivalently, `argv + 1` should serve your purpose.  If you get misbehavior when using the former then it is caused by the code that you do not show.  We cannot explain that without a [mcve].

Comment: @JohnBollinger I think you're right. Now I'm scratching my head as to why my code can handle `argv` but not `argv + 1`

Comment: Oh I figured it out, sorry everyone. Thanks @JohnBollinger

Comment: @JohnBollinger why is pointer arithmetic `&argv[1]` equivalent to `argv + 1`. Why do I not have to say `argv + sizeof(argv[0])`

Comment: The unit for pointer arithmetic is the size of the pointed-to type.  In fact, the indexing operator is ***defined*** in terms of pointer arithmetic, so that `a[i]` *means* `*((a) + (i))`.  Therefore `&a[i]` means `&*((a) + (i))` which is equivalent to `((a) + (i))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed both `&argv[1]` and `argv + 1` work (thanks John Bollinger).

My segmentation fault was caused by using the un-altered `argc` value in other parts of my code (should obviously have been using `argc - 1`).

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate `char** argv` using standard pointer arithmetics:

```
char** arguments_from_second_onwards = argv + 1;    
char* second_argument = *(argv + 1);
assert(argv[1] == arguments_from_second_onwards[0]);
```

Comment: Yes, but this does not explain why the OP receives the error he describes.